# Run Mocha programmatically and pass results to variable or function

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mocha.js

I've setup a suite of tests in mocha using ZombieJS and Chai. The tests load up a website and check if various services are booked in correctly and are displaying to visitors of the website.

What I'm aiming for is that the tests will run daily and then email the results to my team. The tests are all running as expected but the blockage I've hit is the following.

How do I pass the JSON reporter results to another node.js script where I can email the results. Building the email and sending it is going to be straight forward using nodemailer and underscore templating.

My current thinking is there are two approaches. Run the mocha test with a shell script and pipe the JSON output to a node script and process the JSON from a  command line argument. Something like...

```
mocha test/services/homepage.js > node email.js
```

The other alternative is to run the tests from within a node script and get the returned result in a variable. I've been using information from here to run the tests within node.

https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically

This runs correctly but I'm lost with how to get the JSON reporter results into a variable from the below code.

```
var Mocha = require('mocha'),
    Suite = Mocha.Suite,
    Runner = Mocha.Runner,
    Test = Mocha.Test;

// First, you need to instantiate a Mocha instance

var mocha = new Mocha({
    reporter: 'json'
});

var suite = new Suite('JSON suite', 'root');
var runner = new Runner(suite);
var mochaReporter = new mocha._reporter(runner);

mocha.addFile(
    '/Users/dominic/Git/testing-rig/test/services/homepage.js'
);

runner.run(function(failures) {
    // the json reporter gets a testResults JSON object on end
    var testResults = mochaReporter.testResults;

    console.log(testResults);
    // send your email here
});
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can listen to the runner events as in https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/lib/runner.js#L40 and build your own report.

```js
var Mocha = require('mocha');

var mocha = new Mocha({});

mocha.addFile('/Users/dominic/Git/testing-rig/test/services/homepage.js')

mocha.run()
    .on('test', function(test) {
        console.log('Test started: '+test.title);
    })
    .on('test end', function(test) {
        console.log('Test done: '+test.title);
    })
    .on('pass', function(test) {
        console.log('Test passed');
        console.log(test);
    })
    .on('fail', function(test, err) {
        console.log('Test fail');
        console.log(test);
        console.log(err);
    })
    .on('end', function() {
        console.log('All done');
    });
```

Comment: Sorry about the slow reply Riaan. This solves my problem exactly. Congrats on your first accepted answer.

Comment: When I use this snipped, I get alle the infos. But mocha also prints everything to stdout. Is there a way to suppress this behavior and only get data of the tests without any output? Thanks in advice!

Comment: Acutally i found my answer here: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/138#issuecomment-142608295

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using a mocha reporter as explained here
https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Third-party-reporters

invoke mocha like this

```
MyReporter = require('./MyReporter');
mocha({ reporter: MyReporter })`
```

and the `MyReporter.js` file will look like this

```
var mocha = require('mocha');
module.exports = MyReporter;

function MyReporter(runner) {
  mocha.reporters.Base.call(this, runner);
  var passes = 0;
  var failures = 0;

  runner.on('pass', function(test){
    passes++;
    console.log('pass: %s', test.fullTitle());
  });

  runner.on('fail', function(test, err){
    failures++;
    console.log('fail: %s -- error: %s', test.fullTitle(), err.message);
  });

  runner.on('end', function(){
    console.log('end: %d/%d', passes, passes + failures);
    process.exit(failures);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm normally people would use a CI bot to achieve what you are trying to do. However, regarding your direct question about getting the result from JSON reporter, I don't know if there is a better way to achieve it, but here is what I'd do after reading the mocha source. You'll have to create the Suite, the Runner and get the reporter yourself (copy from https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/test%2Freporters%2Fjson.js):

```
var mocha = new Mocha({
    reporter: 'json'
});
var suite = new Suite('JSON suite', 'root');
var runner = new Runner(suite);
var mochaReporter = new mocha._reporter(runner);

runner.run(function(failures) {
    // the json reporter gets a testResults JSON object on end
    var testResults = mochaReporter.testResults;
    // send your email here
});
```

Comment: When i console log `testResults` i get undefined so it doesn't look like the suggested solution is working. I'd be interested in hearing more about the CI Bot you mentioned.

Comment: @dlearious sorry, my bad. _reporter is the constructor, not the instance. Updated my answer.

Comment: @dlearious regarding CI, we use jenkins where I work. Instead of JSON reporter, we use a jUnit-style XML reporter. After every build, Jenkins will read this report and send us notice :)

Comment: Thanks for the info about jenkins, i have looked into it briefly but its probably a bit advanced for what i need at the moment, one for the future maybe.

Comment: I've updated my question with the current code to run mocha. When i log the testResults i still get undefined. If i log `MochaReporter` i get the following  `{ stats: { suites: 0, tests: 0, passes: 0, pending: 0, failures: 0 }` so it doesn't look like its loading the tests, something relates to the Suite maybe?

Comment: @dlearious oops, we also need to update the code to be `runner.run` instead of `mocha.run`. I've updated my answer. Please try again.

Comment: Looks like its pretty close as the json is coming back correctly. I'm still getting 0 tests run, do i need to update how i'm adding tests for the reporter to work. Thanks for all the help so far :)

Comment: @dlearious Can you try absolute path to your test files? If that doesn't work, I'm officially out of suggestions :) good luck

Comment: @dlearious if using absolute path proves to be necessary, your relative path is probably incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for all the help but the absolute path didn't fix the issue. Before i added the new reporter the tests were running so the paths don't seem to be the issue. Anyway thanks for all your input and patience :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone looking for a answer in 2024
You Can get the `testResults` from the runner like this `runner.testResults`

```
    const Mocha = require("mocha");
    const { readFileSync } = require("fs");

    const mocha = new Mocha({
      reporter: "json",
    });

    mocha.addFile("./test/index.test.js");

    runner = mocha.run();

    runner.on("end", function () {
      console.log(runner.testResults);
      console.log("All done");
       // Send you mail here
    });
```